# Not getting option of checkin/checkout option while editing page in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, check-out, check-in

I am not getting option of checkin/checkout while editing page in SP Online

https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/root/abc/test.aspx

[image]

while I am getting checki/checkout options at root site while editing page.
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/root/

Note : I have used share gate to migrate these subsite from one site collection to another but even If I create new page at https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/root/abc/ I am not getting check in options

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of page you want to edit with this issue?

If you edit the web part page, it's the default behavior. There is no Check in/out button on Page tab of web part pages.

We can only check in/out the page through ECB menu of the web part page or through the Check in/out button on Document tab in the relevant pages library.